# Global maxima with two dimensional functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

if I only have one critical point (in my case a maximum) and no minimum within the domain, can I conclude that that critical point is a global max.?

Observe $f(x,y)=6\sqrt(x)y^{1/3}-3x-y$ for example.

Comment: What is the domain you are considering for $f$?

Comment: $[0,\infty)\times [0,\infty )$

Comment: If I am not mistaken $f$ is concave. In that case, any critical point must be a global maximum (this is not true in general).

Comment: What if the domain is compact?

Comment: If the domain is compact and $f$ is continuous, then you are certain that $f$ has a global maximum and a global minimum somewhere in its domain. If this global maximum is in the interior of the domain then it must be a critical point. Unfortunately this is not always the case: consider the function $x\mapsto x$ on $[0,1]$. It has a global maximum and minimum, but neither of those points are critical points.